# Retrieving the value from dataTable

Tags: datatable, datarow

how to retrieve the value(string form) from dataTable and assign that value to int varaible.. would any one pls give idea about this

Comment: I am using mysql as a database, i want get the memberid from the database that is string representation of integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DataTable table = GetTable();  //Gets the DataTable
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
          foreach (var item in row.ItemArray) // Loops over all the items.
          {
            string val = item;      
          }
    }
```

Comment: great if it's woking for you can you please mark my answer as the right one. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
int value = 0;
int.tryParse(DataTable.Rows[0][0].ToString(), out value);
```